# Create association between two instancied objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many, belongs-to

I have two models: (Albums and Product)

1) Inside Models

Inside album.rb:

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :products
end
```

Inside product.rb:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :img, :name, :price, :quantity
  belongs_to :album
end
```

2) Using "**rails console**", how can I set the associations (so I can use "<%= Product.first.album.name %>")?

e.g.

```
a = Album.create( :name => "My Album" )
p = Product.create( :name => "Shampoo X" )
# what's next? how can i set the album and the product together?
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
a = Album.create( name: "My Album" )

p = Product.create( name: "Shampoo X" )
# OR
p = Product.create( name: "Shampoo X", album_id: a.id )
# OR
p.album = a
# OR
p.album_id = a.id
# OR 
a.products << a
# finish with a save of the object:
p.save
```

You may have to set the attribute accessible to album_id on the Product model (not sure about that).

**Check @bdares' comment also.**

Comment: If you add the `_id` to accessible, then you can just stick the id value as you instantiate it: `Product.create(name:'Shampoo',album_id:a.id)`

Comment: @bdares To add _id, I just have to use `attr_accessible :img, :name, :price, :quantity, :_id`, right? However, it gives me this error, `ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: album_id`

Comment: @MrYoshiji, For `p.album = a`, it temporarily works, but if I reopen the console, the p.album turns into "nil". For `p.album_id = a.id`, it gives this error, `NoMethodError: undefined method 'album_id='`. For `a.products << p`, it gives this error, `RuntimeError: can't modify frozen Hash`. Do I need to regenerate both models? Thank you everyone!

Comment: You have to give access to the album_id attribute: `attr_accessible :img, :name, :price, :quantity, :album_id`

Comment: Thanks! Apparently, I have to recreate the Product Model to have `album_id:integer`, not just add it in `attr_accessible`.

Comment: Yes you have to generate a migration (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html) in order to add the new column `album_id` as integer in the database.

Answer (score 2):

Add the association when you create the Product:

```
a = Album.create( :name => "My Album" )
p = Product.create( :name => "Shampoo X", :album => a )
```

Comment: It temporarily works. However, if I reopen the console, the p.album turns into "nil"..

Comment: Are you fetching the same `Product` you created the first time? Try the above code, then reopen the console and try `Product.find_by_name('Shampoo X').album`.