# Association on primary key not percolating to view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, rails-activerecord

In a rails view

```
<%= packageoffer.id %> <%= packageoffer.structure.nil? %>
```

returns `3817 true`

Yet, when queried in console

```
al = Available.find(3817)
al.structure
```

returns an object. `#<Structure id: "CAF401100", product_code: "CAF401100", [...]`
Thus `packageoffer.structure.nil?` in the view ought to return `false`!

Attempting to figure out what is going on... The classes are defined in such a way to create the association, as proven by the console query:

```
class Available < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :structure, class_name: 'Structure', primary_key: 'product_code'

class Structure < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = 'product_code'
  has_many :availables, primary_key: :product_code
```

The controller action is a bit complex, assembling two arrays originating from different classes:

```
@availables = Available.where(['event_id = ?', @event.id]).to_a
@packageoffers = (@packageoffers_a + @availables).sort_by(&:cost)
```

and the view then conditionally processes the assembled array

```
@packageoffers.each do |packageoffer|
  if @availables.include?(packageoffer)
```

which then tries to invoke the relationship

```
    packageoffer.structure.nil?
```

why is the association not accessible at this point?

**update** one line of thought is that being a sum of two arrays, the sumed array `@packageoffers` has no structural knowledge about the relationship of Class Available.  How can that be re-established in this case?

Comment: Does your structure model have a relationship to a packageoffer model somwhere? It seems there should be a `belongs_to :packageoffer` in the structure model definition; not sure if you just didn't include it or if it does not exist. Post the packageoffer class definition also.

Comment: There is a Packageoffer class. However, no associations are defined there relative to Available Class. No model `belongs_to :packageoffer`  either...

Comment: OK, well, what is the relationship between packageoffer and structure? When you invoke `packageoffer.structure` you are evidently expecting them to have some sort of relationship.

Comment: packageoffer is a construct, an assembly of two arrays.  one source of the array - availables - has objects which belong to structure.  as stated in question, the console generates the association, but the view does not.

Comment: Ah. OK, you may want to update your question. It's not at all clear at first why you expect packageoffer 3817 to have something in common with available 3817.
Also, your associations presented here are not symmetrical. if `Available belongs_to :structure` they you should also specify that `Structure has_many :availables`. And, you might want to try restarting your rails console to see if what you're seeing is still true after the restart.

Comment: Structure does have the has_many association defined. so the question is amended. restarting the console now results in a nil association.  I guess, I shuffled enought changes that the console was out of synch.  The above set-up is now (not the goal) returning consistently nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that after restarting the console you are seeing a `nil` each time you call `.structure` on this object. In that case you have not yet successfully saved a structure foreign key to this the object.

If you were attempting to set this association via the console, you may be a victim of the misleading fact that there are circumstances under which associations you set in the console are not actually written to the database and don't persist. If so, this discussion may be helpful to you: [Create association between two instancied objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034844/create-association-between-two-instancied-objects)

Answer (score 0):

Lesson 1:

when defining these non-standard associations, restart console after EACH change, to avoid being sent on a garden path.

Lesson 2:

Do not confuse foreign and primary keys.  The issue got resolved by defining the association as:

```
belongs_to :structure, class_name: 'Structure', foreign_key: 'product_code
```

Comment: Glad this got figured out! If my comments helped you realize that the console was misleading you, please accept my answer as correct.